# Encrypted file isn't correctly decrypted

Tags: c#, encryption, serialization

I have the following issue: there is a class called `UserConfigStorage`, in which there are 8 strings. Once the program runs for first time, the user is asked to input their personal information, and these are stored in the 8 strings aforementioned. Once the user clicks a button, this class is serialized and encrypted, to prevent the user from modifying it. Then, when the program is run for a second time, upon `Form_Load` event, the file is decrypted, and the info in it is load to the textBoxes using a Deserializing method. However, there's an exception `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed` thrown, and the file can't be read.

When looking into the code and the files generated, I found that the decrypted file generated doesn't have all the info. It actually only has 6 of the 8 strings that are stored.

The methods are as follow:

**SERIALIZING METHOD**

```
    public void SerializeUserConfig(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
            binForm.Serialize(fileStream, userconfigstorage);
            fileStream.Close();

            encryptor.Encrypt(fileName, perfilAcesso.GetUserConfigPath() + "Encrypted", "syndra15OP");

            File.Delete(fileName);

            MessageBox.Show("Dados salvos com sucesso!");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            errorlog.SetError(exception.ToString());
            SerializeError(perfilAcesso.GetUserErrorLogPath());
            MessageBox.Show("Houve um erro ao salvar as configurações!\nPor favor, contate o desenvolvedor.\n\nEID: 002");
        }
    }
```

**DESERIALIZING METHOD**

```
    public UserConfigStorage DeserializeUserConfig(string fileName)
    {
        encryptor.Decrypt(perfilAcesso.GetUserConfigPath() + "Encrypted", fileName, "syndra15OP");

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
        UserConfigStorage userconfigstorage = (UserConfigStorage)binForm.Deserialize(fileStream);
        fileStream.Close();
        return userconfigstorage;
    }
```

**ENCRYPTING METHOD (is in a `Encryptor` class)**

```
    public void Encrypt(string input, string output, string strHash)
    {
        FileStream inStream, outStream;
        CryptoStream cryStream;
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdc = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        byte[] byteHash, byteText;

        inStream = new FileStream(input, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        outStream = new FileStream(output, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

        byteHash = md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strHash));
        byteText = File.ReadAllBytes(input);

        md5.Clear();

        tdc.Key = byteHash;
        tdc.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

        cryStream = new CryptoStream(outStream, tdc.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        int bytesRead;
        long length, position = 0;
        length = inStream.Length;

        while (position < length)
        {
            bytesRead = inStream.Read(byteText, 0, byteText.Length);
            position += bytesRead;

            cryStream.Write(byteText, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        inStream.Close();
        outStream.Close();
        cryStream.Close();
    }
```

**DECRYPTING METHOD**

```
//The same as Encrypt(), except that for cryStream, it's tdc.CreateDecryptor()
```

**CLASS TO BE SERIALIZED**

```
[Serializable()]
public class UserConfigStorage
{
    // 8 strings here, all public, each with its public getter
}
```

Could anybody help me as to what is causing the file not to be fully decrypted? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: and where you are closing cryStream ?

Comment: Forgot to add that! After closing `inStream` and `outStream`.

Comment: so you are closing outer stream after inner is closed? does it looks reasonable for you? what if outer stream would like to write something on `Close`/`Dispose` and but inner is closed? why didn't you just use `using` ? `using(var outStream =...) { using(var cryStream = ...) { }  }`

Comment: Ok, now I feel very stupid for not realising the order of closing streams. My apologies for such a dumb mistake. And yes, use `using` makes more sense in this case, I just hadn't thought of that. Much appreciated!

Comment: also remeber about `Stream.CopyTo(...)` so you code would look like  `using(var outStream = new FileStream(output, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)) { using(var cryStream = (outStream, tdc.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)) { inStream.CopyTo(cryStream);  } }` ... now your code use really strange buffer size `byteText.Length` whch is length of while file

Comment: Yes, a better-looking approach! Thanks once more. Could you please answer the question with the info about the order of stream closing, so I can accept it? It's more than fair, given the help it is for me hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) is definitely your friend here! :)

Why are you serializing the object into a file, just to encrypt it into another file afterwards?

I have cleaned your code a bit up, this should work as expected:

```
public void SerializeUserConfig(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        Encrypt(userconfigstorage, Path.Combine(perfilAcesso.GetUserConfigPath(), fileName), "syndra15OP");
        MessageBox.Show("Dados salvos com sucesso!");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        errorlog.SetError(exception.ToString());
        SerializeError(perfilAcesso.GetUserErrorLogPath());
        MessageBox.Show("Houve um erro ao salvar as configurações!\nPor favor, contate o desenvolvedor.\n\nEID: 002");
    }
}

public UserConfigStorage DeserializeUserConfig(string fileName)
{
    return Decrypt(Path.Combine(perfilAcesso.GetUserConfigPath(), fileName), "syndra15OP");
}

public void Encrypt(UserConfigStorage input, string filePath, string strHash)
{
    using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdc = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        using (FileStream outStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {

            using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                tdc.Key = md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strHash));
                md5.Clear();
            }

            tdc.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

            using (CryptoStream cryStream = new CryptoStream(outStream, tdc.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
                binForm.Serialize(cryStream, input);
            }
        }
    }
}

public UserConfigStorage Decrypt(string filePath, string strHash)
{
    UserConfigStorage output;

    using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdc = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        using (FileStream outStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {

            using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                tdc.Key = md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strHash));
                md5.Clear();
            }

            tdc.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

            using (CryptoStream cryStream = new CryptoStream(outStream, tdc.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
                output = binForm.Deserialize(cryStream) as UserConfigStorage;
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Regards